# Integration with Laplace transforms

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, laplace-method

I have this problem to solve, but I couldn't get the solution:

$F(s) = \frac{s-2}{s^{2}-1}$

$s>1$

$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left ( \frac{f(t)}{e^{2t}} \right )dt$

$L\left [ e^{-2t}f(t)) \right ]=F\left ( s-a \right )=\frac{s}{(s+2)^{2}-1}$

and

$L\left [ \int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{f(t))}{e^{2t}} \right ) \right ] = \frac{F(s))}{s}=\frac{1}{(s+2)^{2}-1}$

so

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{f(t))}{e^{2t}} \right ) = L^{-1}\left [ \frac{1}{(s+2)^{2}-1}  \right ]$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{f(t))}{e^{2t}} \right ) = \frac{1}{2}\left ( e^{-t} + e^{-3t} \right )$

I am struggling to solve this with Laplace properties. I have to evaluate the integral without explicitly calculate *f(t)*. *F(s)* is the Laplace transform of *f(t)*. I suppose that my resolution is wrong since the superior limit is *infinity*. **The solution must be achieved without performing  *f(t)* at the beginning**. **The method must use *F(s)* and not *f(t)* directly on the integral.**
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The integal is just $F(2)$.

Comment: If you are writing $F(s)$ for the Laplace transform of $f$ then $F(2)$ is equal to that integral **by definition**.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy - How?

Comment: Just use partial fractions and already proved Laplace transforms. Please edit your post and make it easier to understand what exactly you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

$$
F(s)=\frac{s-2}{s^{2}-1},\quad{s}\gt{1}.
\\
L^{-1}\left[F(s)\right]=L^{-1}\left[\frac{s-2}{s^{2}-1}\right]=L^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^{2}-1}\right]+L^{-1}\left[\frac{-2}{s^{2}-1}\right]=
\\
=\left(\cosh(t)-2\sinh(t)\right)=\frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}-2e^{t}+2e^{-t}}{2}=\frac{-e^{t}+3e^{-t}}{2},\implies
\\
\implies{f(t)}=\frac{-e^{t}+3e^{-t}}{2}.
$$
$$
\int{\frac{(-e^{t}+3e^{-t})e^{-2t}}{2}}dt=\left(\int{\frac{-e^{-t}}{2}}dt+\int{\frac{3e^{-3t}}{2}}dt\right)=0.5e^{-t}-1.5e^{-3t}.
$$